# Mercurial: Move a modified file between commits

Tags: mercurial

Let's say I have the following commit history:

```
A - newest
B
C - oldest
```

I have changed a file `foo` in B, but I want to move the change from B to A.

How can I do that with `hg`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several different ways that I can think of. Both have some moderate user requirements (please make sure you have backed up or pushed to a non-publishing repository first).

1 ) Use histedit and amend (requires that each extensions be enabled).

```
- copy file you wish to move to a safe location
- run hg histedit and edit changeset b and restore file to its original state
- run hg histedit --continue to commit changes.
- copy file from safe location to repository
- run hg amend to append file to changeset A
```

2 )  Use split and histedit.

```
- run hg split -r b

    - split out all but the file you wish to move into a new changeset

    - create a new changeset onto of that containing the fie (give it a temporary description)

- run hg histedit

    - move the temp change above A

    - roll the temp change into A
```

3 ) Use hg-evolve uncommit / amend. While this is a somewhat advanced method, I much prefer this one myself.

```
- run hg update B

- run hg uncommit and select the file you wish to move.

- run hg evolve to correct the stack

- run hg update A

    Note: if you get a warning about needing to use --clean use hg shelve before
            running the update followed by hg unshelve afterwords.

- run hg amend to add file to change A
```

4 ) Use hg uncommit all contents of changesets A and B and then recommit using hg commit -i to reassemble the changesets with the desired content.

There are likely a number of other ways, but this is what came to me.

Comment: I came to option 3 by myself — thanks for sharing all the options!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplistic but functional approach, maybe for people not very experienced with some of the more advanced HG commands:

0. Make sure your working directory is clean (no changes).
1. `hg update -r C`
2. `hg revert -r B`
3. `hg commit` ... as needed, but leave out the change destined for `A`. This creates `B'`.
4. `hg shelve` ... store away the uncommitted changes
5. `hg revert -r A`
6. `hg unshelve` ... restore uncommitted changes, merging them into the workding directory
7. `hg commit` ... creates `C'`.
8. `hg strip -r B` ... (optional!)

(where it says `-r A` that means use the revision # corresponding to `A`)

**Explanation:**  we just create two (or more) entirely new changesets and then delete the originals (which is optional).

We're using `revert` basically to mean "copy from some changeset to the working directory" which I find is very handy in many circumstances.

After these operations -- but prior to using `strip` -- the history would look like:

```
   *
   |
A  A'
|  |
B  B'
|/
C
```

and `strip` will just delete `A`, `B`.